# Audio encoding via IIS mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am uploading audio file to server normally, now I want to get the mp3 file 196kbps and set to 128kbps.

```
NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader wave = new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(stream);
Id3.Mp3Stream wave2 = new Id3.Mp3Stream(stream, Id3.Mp3Permissions.ReadWrite);
```

I can load all information about the mp3 but I cant modify anything about audio quality. Any option/slampe to do that on asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

Read this article about audio converting in .NET
You can all things you can do in .NET in ASP,NET.
 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/501521/How-to-convert-between-most-audio-formats-in-NET